How to fix issue with column alignment when printing pandas dataframe with emojis?
When printing a DataFrame with emojis, the column header alignment issue worsens with more columns. This doesn't happen without emojis. Any solutions?
With Emojis
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',    1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.width',       1000)

example = {'normal_col'  : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           'text_col'    : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_A' : [' hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_B' : [' hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_C' : [' hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_D' : [' hello world'] * 10}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)

print(df)

   normal_col     text_col    emoji_col_A    emoji_col_B    emoji_col_C    emoji_col_D
0           1  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
1           2  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
2           3  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
3           4  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
4           5  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
5           6  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
6           7  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
7           8  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
8           9  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world
9          10  hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world   hello world

Without Emojis
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',    1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.width',       1000)

example = {'normal_col'  : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           'text_col'    : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_A' : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_B' : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_C' : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_D' : ['hello world'] * 10}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)

print(df)

   normal_col     text_col  emoji_col_A  emoji_col_B  emoji_col_C  emoji_col_D
0           1  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
1           2  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
2           3  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
3           4  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
4           5  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
5           6  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
6           7  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
7           8  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
8           9  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world
9          10  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world  hello world


Terminal emulators/consoles treat most characters as having a width of one terminal unit. Han ideographs, emoji in emoji presentation, full width characters and some others need to be treated as wide characters (Taking up two terminal widths). In Python the wcwidth module is sueful building toools for the console.
But specifically with Pandas there are two approaches:

Force emoji to be treated as wide characters. Pandas has options for this, and they are detailed in Chris Fu's answer., so I will not go into that solution.
force emoji into text representation instead of emoji representation.

Emoji potentially have two visual representations:

as emoji: for many emoji this is the default representation. It can be explicitly set using Variation Selector 16 (U+FE0F). Emoji will have a width of 2 terminal cells.
as text: for some emoji this is the default representation. It can be explicitly set using Variation Selector 15 (U+FE0E). Emoji will have text representation (if terminal/console will switch to an appropriate font) and will take up a width of one terminal cell.

The following code works on macOS in terminal, iTerm2 and the VSCode integrated terminal. On other platforms it will be dependent on the terminal/console being used.
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',    1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.width',       1000)

example = {'normal_col'  : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
           'text_col'    : ['hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_A' : ['\uFE0E hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_B' : ['\uFE0E hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_C' : ['\uFE0E hello world'] * 10,
           'emoji_col_D' : ['\uFE0E hello world'] * 10}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)

print(df)

This displays as:

Either approach 1) or approach 2) should work, although both depend on terminal/console support.

Didn't know you were a unicode wizard!

That's the easy stuff re Python and Unicode.

First, you need a strict 1:2 sized font (e.g. Inconsolata) for your console.
Then, change some Pandas options before you display a DataFrame.
import pandas

pandas.options.display.unicode.east_asian_width = True
pandas.options.display.unicode.ambiguous_as_wide = True

For the example you gave in OP, switching east_asian_width to True alone should be enough.

Is there a way to force the emojis to be only 1:1 character width?

@AlanSTACK not unless your pick a different emoji (one with a width of 1)

@AlanSTACK, emoji have a terminal cell width of two, like Han ideographs. If you really want a single terminal cell for the emoji, you might want to force them to text mode rather than emoji mode.

@Andj And how exactly would you do what you are suggesting?

@AlanSTACK, added an answer showing the second approach. But setting CJK options as detailed by Chris Fu is an appropriate solution. I have no personal preference for either the first or second approach. Both work for me. The problem area isn't emoji, there are ways to handle it. If you want a real challenge try mixing emoji with Arabic or Adlam script text when displaying a dataframe.

You can use df.style.set_properties():
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows',    1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.width',       1000)

example = {'normal_col'  : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'text_col'    : ['hello world'] * 10,
       'emoji_col_A' : [' hello world'] * 10,
       'emoji_col_B' : [' hello world'] * 10,
       'emoji_col_C' : [' hello world'] * 10,
       'emoji_col_D' : [' hello world'] * 10}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)
y = df.style.set_properties()
display(y)


y = df.style.set_properties() isn't actually doing anything. You need to pass a dictionary of property, value pairs. All the above code is doing is teh equivalent of display(df) which will display the dataframe correctly without any additional configuration. Displaying a dataframe in a notebook using higher level protocols is very dirrferent to printing a dataframe in a terminal.
